# MobaXterm fails to connect via SSH

Tags: ssh

I am facing a problem with MobaXterm when I try to connect to specific Linux machines. I get an error "Connection reset by peer". If I try to connect using putty, it works fine. If I use MobaXterm with other servers, it works fine.

Should I be changing any settings to get MobaXterm work ?

Comment: What does the sshd log say when the connection is reset?  You might have to set LogLevel DEBUG in sshd, then restart it.  Is the cygwin-sshd tag correct here?  You said you're connecting to Linux machines.